# I created this CHECK Constraint to guarantee at least 2 of the 4 fields are equivalent in an entry. Why is it not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to create a constraint to enforce each row to have at least two of the four fields equivalent to each other.

I came up with

```
    CHECK(
    (CASE WHEN (CAMPO1=CAMPO2)
    OR (CAMPO1=CAMPO3)
    OR (CAMPO1=CAMPO4) 
    OR (CAMPO2=CAMPO3)
    OR (CAMPO2=CAMPO4)
    OR (CAMPO3 = CAMPO4)
    THEN 1 END) = 1 );
```

However, to my surprise, the following INSERT statement went through.

```
INSERT INTO Ejercicio2A_2(
    CAMPO1,
    CAMPO2,
    CAMPO3,
    CAMPO4)
VALUES('A','B','C','D')
```

None of the values are equal to the other so I needed the constraint to reject the INSERT statement. Why did it not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why did it not?

SQL uses three valued logic. Boolean expressions can evaluate to `true`, `false`, or `unknown`.

You would need an `ELSE 0`

Otherwise the `CASE` expression evaluates to `NULL`.

`NULL = 1` is `unknown`.

Check constraints only reject `false` values and allow `true` and `unknown`.

But, as @Gordon points out there would be no value in doing

```
CHECK (CASE WHEN  <CONDITION> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 );
```

anyway - and this should just be written

```
CHECK (<CONDITION>);
```

Answer (score 3):

No `case` expression is necessary:

```
(CAMPO1 = CAMPO2 OR CAMPO1 = CAMPO3 OR CAMPO1 = CAMPO4 OR
 CAMPO2 = CAMPO3 OR CAMPO2 = CAMPO4 OR
 CAMPO3 = CAMPO4
)
```

Or more concisely as:

```
(CAMPO1 IN (CAMPO2, CAMPO3, CAMPO4) OR
 CAMPO2 IN (CAMPO3, CAMPO4) OR
 CAMPO3 IN (CAMPO4)
)
```